# Handling quirks mode and standards mode on one page in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, coldfusion, quirks-mode

I'm trying to implement a jQuery photo editor in to an old (very old) admin back-end which is only working in ie quirks mode. But the new jQuery Plugin will not work in quirks mode.

I found out that an iFrame would help to prevent ie from rendering the page section in quirks mode but the security on the back-end restricts the use of iFrames. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902255/run-quirks-mode-in-one-frame-and-standards-mode-in-another). So the solution wasn't useful for my problem.

The page is written in Adobe ColdFusion and the security is very restricting. 
Would be glad with any suggestions or experiences with the quirks mode which may help me solve my problem.

(I didn't found very useful information about the quirks mode on the web maybe causing by the fact that is an obsolete thematic?! So if you have any useful references I would thankful take them:) )

Comment: You either need to fix the page to work outside of quirks mode or try the iframe solution. Are you sure you can't use iframes? What is preventing it?

Comment: Fixing the page is not really an option since it would be too much effort.

I would like to use an iFrame but it causes the log-in window to appear.

Comment: Use an [object tag](http://www.felgall.com/noiframe.htm) instead, with the correct [doctype](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/doctypes) in the embedded jQuery document.