# How to force Iframe to run quirks under a standard parent frame

Tags: html, iframe

We have a parent page that must run in IE9 standard mode, executing HTML5 commands.
Underneath we have an iframe that must run in compatibility mode (IE7/8).

In IE9, as I understand, iframes inherits their doctype from parent. is that correct?
Is there any solution for this issue? can , somehow, iframe be executed with quirks doctype under standard mode doctype parent frame?
thanks,
Tal

Comment: See this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/5624373/572939

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run quirks mode in one frame and standards mode in another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902255/run-quirks-mode-in-one-frame-and-standards-mode-in-another)

Comment: These do not provides answers - since it forces the whole page running in IE7 mode. The required behavior is to enable IE9 mode in parent, yet quirks mode in iframe inside.

Comment: Can you just use some normalization techniques to fix the ugliness that the child iframe bleeds into its parent? E.g. http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/ ?

Comment: I did extensive research on this some time back for a project (more links than I care to post here). My conclusion: there is absolutely no way to do it, and it would solve a lot of problems if there were. That being said, it's possible (I don't know your use case) to achieve a similar result using VB.NET and WebBrowser controls, if that's part of your tech stack.

Comment: take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467151/iframe-not-rendering-in-ie9-mode-when-containing-page-is-in-quirks-mode

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not possible to trigger a different rendering mode in a child iframe in IE9, as officially documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558056(v=vs.85).aspx (emphasis added):

> Although the newer rendering engine is only used when Windows Internet
>   Explorer detects that an HTML page has requested the highest level of
>   support for standards, the same is not always true for child pages
>   that might be loaded within frame and iframe elements. ***Because only
>   one rendering engine can be active at a time***, IE9 Mode also includes
>   emulation for Quirks Mode.

However, as it says, you **can** trigger **"quirks mode emulation"** which leaves the IE9 rendering engine active but alters its behavior in several ways to match the old quirks mode.

JSBin demo: http://jsbin.com/ozejuk/1/

This example has a div with style `background: #ff0000; background: 00ff00; border-radius: 30px` ... in quirks mode, hex colors without `#` are accepted. In IE9 mode they are not. Loading the demo in IE9 will show a red div in the parent page, and a green div (but still with rounded corners) in the iframe.

How to trigger quirks mode emulation in an iframe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558096(v=vs.85).aspx

Short version: omit DOCTYPE, add: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`

Complete list of effects quirks mode emulation has on rendering: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558047(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response, Nick. I'll look into it later today or next week.

Comment: Unfortunately, emulating quirks mode doesn't appear to resolve my issue, which is this: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2928139 Thanks again for the reply. I appreciate the effort you put into it. +1.

Comment: Apparently in IE10+ you can trigger different rendering mode in a child.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206688/ie11-quirks-mode-under-iframe-javascript-errors/41270772#41270772