# Parent document is in Standards mode but Inner Iframe document (without doctype) runs in wierd mode in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I have a webpage that runs in standards mode. The webpage hosts iframes linking to visitors home pages over which I have no control. I have observed that those visitors home pages which run in quirks run well as standalone , but once loaded in the inner iframe, their styles breaks up.

It appears the inner document is running in IE5 quirks!

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723724/how-to-force-iframe-to-run-quirks-under-a-standard-parent-frame

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, there's no work-around, the document type is always inherited from the parent page in IE > 8.

Your options are:

```
a) Open the page in a new tab
b) Put your page into quirks mode 
   (if you do, all pages requiring non-quirksmode won't work, 
    that includes iframe & parent page pages)
c) Ask the site owner to please update his HTML to be standards-compliant
```

You can however put your main page into IE8 mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

That however will break all pages requiring IE9+ features.