# IE 11 document mode for iframe page when parent page is running in edge mode

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-11, quirks-mode

**Problem** - We are trying to migrate our application to use IE Edge mode (we are using IE 11 browser). Our application consists of a top level page and a child iframe to load third party applications (which may load from a domain which is different from parent page domain). As part of migration, parent level page now loads in Edge mode (using IE=Edge value for X-UA-Compatible meta tag)

**Question** - Can i be absolutely sure that iframe page will always render in Edge mode as well (irrespective of its malformed content or the use of X-UA-Compatible meta tag with a different content value)? Is there any official msdn document confirming the same?

Note:

1. I checked [this msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955402(v=vs.85).aspx) link, but it mainly explains IE9 behavior, and it also talks about the case where an iframe cannot have document mode higher than that of parent page.
2. Based on my understanding, the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206688/ie11-quirks-mode-under-iframe-javascript-errors) seems to indicate that iframe will also render in Edge mode, but i am not entirely sure.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx :

> As of IE9 mode, webpages cannot display multiple document modes. For
>   example, consider a standards-based webpage that contains a frame
>   element that displays content in quirks mode. IE9 mode displays the
>   child frame in standards mode (because the parent document is in
>   standards mode). Starting with Internet Explorer 10, however, child
>   frames can emulate quirks mode. For more info, see IEBlog: HTML5
>   Quirks mode in IE10. For best results, however, use document modes
>   consistently.

This means that If you set the X-UA-Compatible meta tag, if IE version is newer than 9 it will display the current window and all child browsing contexts in Edge mode. If the IE version is 8 (the version in which this meta tag is introduced), this can render child contexts using different rendering mode.