# Is it possible to load different iframes in the same page with different compatibility modes?

Tags: html, iframe, cross-browser, compatibility, internet-explorer-11

I have a legacy application, where the main page consists of a frameset. The head of this page has a meta tag with X-UA-COMPATIBLE set to IE=5.

I have recently added a new iframe to this set and want it to be using the IE=EDGE mode as i am working with IE-11.

My problem is that the head meta tag overrides the individual iframes meta tag. Note that i would not want to remove the head meta tag as it is important.

All i want to do is load the existing frames in IE=5 mode and this new frame in EDGE mode.

Is it possible to load different iframes in the same page with different compatibility modes ? If yes, then how ?

Answer (score 0):

Nick Blanchard-Wright may have your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15563464/3895252  IE-11 appears to have the same functionality.