# Prevent HEAD Requests for embedded objects in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, object-tag

I am creating a website where my HTML will be embedded within a page that I have no control over. I would like my page to be rendered in IE9 standards mode. In order to do that, I have my first page embed a second page using an embed tag in order to allow the second frame to be in standards mode. This trick is discussed here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332125/can-an-iframe-content-be-rendered-in-standards-mode-when-the-parent-is-rendered](https://superuser.com/questions/560647/ie10-unexpectedly-sends-a-head-request-for-pdf-what-has-changed)

Unfortunately, depending on the version of Internet Explorer, this results in either an extra HEAD request or an extra GET request. This is discussed here:

https://superuser.com/questions/560647/ie10-unexpectedly-sends-a-head-request-for-pdf-what-has-changed

I would like to avoid these extra requests. Does anyone know of a way to do so?

Thanks.