# (IE specific) How can I prevent that my iFrame is shown in the compatiblity mode from its parent HTML-Page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, x-ua-compatible

Here is my IE-specific question:
How can I prevent that my `iFrame` is shown in the compatibility mode from its parent HTML-Page?

I want to find a JavaScript solution for this problem.

Here is my structure:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE7" />
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id='frameMain' src='http://example.com' />
</body>

</html>
```

the `iFrame` `frameMain` will also be displayed in the Compatible-Mode (IE=IE7), but I don't want this!

Does anyone of you know JavaScript (or any other trick) to show the `iFrame` in IE=edge?

please help me!

greetz Klaus

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717932/will-an-iframe-render-in-quirks-mode

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332125/can-an-iframe-content-be-rendered-in-standards-mode-when-the-parent-is-rendered